# How to write tab separated file in R without quotes around text fields

Tags: r, csv, data.table

Example dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(a = c('sdfsd\tdfs"df\tssdf"sd\\'), b = ("test"))
```

Expected output either (tab chars shown as `<tab>`):

```
a<tab>b
sdfsd\<tab>dfs"df\<tab>ssdf"sd\\<tab>test
```

or

```
a<tab>b
sdfsd\tdfs"df\tssdf"sd\\<tab>test
```

I tied

```
write.table(df, file = "test.tsv", sep = "\t", row.names = F, quote = T)
```

produces

```
"a" "b"
"sdfsd<tab>dfs\"df<tab>ssdf\"sd\"<tab>"test"
```

that has quote chars around text fields. Downstream system won't be able to handle these extra quotes correctly.
`write.table` with `quote = FALSE` produces

```
a<tab>b
sdfsd<tab>dfs"df<tab>ssdf"sd\<tab>test
```

which doesn't have quotes but also didn't escape delim character (tab) and escape character (`\`). So the result is not parsable.

I've also tried `fwrite` from `data.table` package. It has similar quick of either quote or no escape.

I.e. I need truly delimiter + escape char format output, not quote based.
Any libraries in R?

Comment: Try `df[[1]] <- gsub("\\t", "\\\\t", df[[1]])` and then write to file?

Comment: if oyu post apply version of it as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061421/how-to-write-tab-separated-file-in-r-without-quotes-around-text-fields?noredirect=1#comment111516391_63061421), here is a `*apply` version of my comment to the question. The embedded tabs `"\t"` are replaced by `"\\t"` in all columns of the data.frame `df`.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\t", "\\\\t", x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rui Barradas comment I will:

```
   df_clean = as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x){ gsub("\t"," ",gsub("\\", "", x, fixed = T), fixed = T) }))

  fwrite(
    df_clean,
    file=f_name,
    sep = "\t",
    quote = F,
    eol = "\n",
    na = "\\N",
    qmethod = "escape",
    compress = "gzip"
  )
```

Kind of silly that write.table, data.table::fwrite, readr::write_tsv, vroom_write all don't inspect dumped fields for delim character (and escape character) and don't escape it.